# Rails: fields_for in fields_for not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a Letter form saving some data with a Message and a Button associated. I use a Message fields_for and a Button fields_for within the Message fields_for. The inputs are displayed but when I submit, the Button data is not saved.

I get this in the rails console:

> Unpermitted parameter: buttons

My form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :messages do |messages_fields| %>
            <div id="text-messenger">
              <div id="DIV_1">
                <%= messages_fields.text_area :content, :required => 'required', class: "autoExpand", id: "intro-text-input", :maxlength => 640, placeholder: "Enter your text...", data: { 'rows' => '3', 'data-min-rows' => '3' } %>
              </div>
              <div id="add-message-button" class="add-button">+ Add Button</div>
              <%= messages_fields.fields_for :buttons do |button_message_fields| %>
                <div class="add-button-modal">
                  <h4>Enter the URL and the text to display on your button</h4>
                  <label>Button Text</label>
                  <%= button_message_fields.text_field :button_text, :maxlength => 20, placeholder: "Enter the text to display on the button..." %>
                  <br><br>
                  <label>Button URL</label>
                  <%= button_message_fields.text_field :button_url, placeholder: "Paste URL..." %>

                  <button type="button" id="validate_new_message_button">Add Button</button>
                  <p class="remove-link" id="delete_new_button">Remove Button</p>
                </div>
              <% end %>
            </div>
          <% end %>
```

My permitted parameters in the Letter controller:

```
def letter_params
      params.require(:letter).permit(:campaign_name, :core_bot_id, :nb_recipients, :scheduled_at,
        filters_attributes: [:id, :gender, :creation_date_start, :creation_date_finish, :first_name, :last_name, :segment => [], :timezone => [], :locale => []],
        messages_attributes: [Message.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:_destroy), buttons_attributes: [Button.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:_destroy)]],
        cards_attributes: Card.attribute_names.map(&:to_sym).push(:_destroy))
    end
```

Letter model:

```
class Letter < ApplicationRecord
  validates :campaign_name, :presence => true

  belongs_to :core_bot
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cards, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :filters, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :analytic_deliveries, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :analytic_reads, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :analytic_sends, dependent: :destroy


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :filters
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards
end
```

Message model:

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :letter, optional: true
  has_one :button, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :button
end
```

Button model:

```
class Button < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :message, optional: true
  belongs_to :card, optional: true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In messenger model, you set `has_one button` relation (not in plural), that mean in params you should have `button_attributes` instead of `buttons_attributes`.another advise, don't put all your attributes in params, only those you want to allow in forms because sometimes, some attributes are calculated on the server side and you don't need the client to fill them.I hope this will help you.